# Is there a verb for "applying/putting gel"?

Tags: word-request

Is there a verb for "applying/putting gel"? Applying or putting doesn't sound like the verb you would use for someone who did his hair with gel before going to school? What's the proper way to say this? I am not necessarily looking for a synonym of applied or put, because I have no idea what people say when commenting about someone's hair.

For example:

> What gel did you ___ on your hair?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As katatahito suggests, "put" or "use" are the most common for this situation.  Either "in" or "on" is fine:

> What kind of gel do you put/use in/on your hair?

Alternately you can *comb* or *brush* gel *into* your hair, but this is a more specific action.

If instead you want to put gel on something other than hair -- for example some kind of chemical treatment -- then "apply" might sound better.

> **Apply** the gel **to** the surface to be treated, and wait ten minutes.

Less formally you can also *smear* gel over something

> As a prank the students **smeared** gel all over the teacher's locker, so that it was too slippery to open.

Comment: What's colloquial about "smear"?

Comment: @Nanigashi Yeah you're right. I should have said "less formally".

Comment: _gel_ is also a verb in its own right, and one of its senses is "apply gel to": _What did you gel your hair with?_

Comment: And there's *slather*, for when you use way too much product in your hair!